# Exception thrown when using malloc() to create an array of characters

Tags: c

Essentially, I'm trying to create a program that simply takes in input from the user and then prints it, using dynamically allocated memory. Yes I know how to do this the simple way, but I'm attempting to get to grips with the intricacies of memory management in C. So what is wrong with this code? it runs without error but when I enter in a string into the command line it stops working and throws an exception at a hexadecimal address.   Thank you in advance.

```
int main() {
  char *input;

  input = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); 
  puts("Enter the string you wish to display"); 
  scanf_s("%s", input); 
  printf_s("%s", *input); 
  free(input);  
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your `#include`s and tell us what platform you use.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler should be warning you about this line:

```
printf_s("%s", *input);
```

If not, you need to enable an "all warnings" setting. (On gcc and clang, add `-Wextra` to the command line.)

Essentially, you have a mismatch between the type of the argument (`char`) and the type expected by the format string (`const char*`). `*input` dereferences the character pointer, and so evaluates to the first character in the string. `"%s"` expects a pointer to a nul-terminated array of characters.

It should work if you remove the `*`:

```
printf_s("%s", input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *input;

  input = malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); // (char *) is not needed here (but doesn't harm either)
  puts("Enter the string you wish to display");
  scanf("%s", input);
  printf("%s", input);  // *input is wrong here
  free(input);
  return 0;
}
```

Don't use the `_s` verions as they are not standard on every platform and more or less pointless, just use `scanf` and `printf`.

Comment: The `_s` versions are in C11.

Comment: They defend against a few more programming errors such as `NULL` pointers. How useful that is in code like this is debatable I suppose.

Comment: Although I agree with you in the broadest sense, I feel it's not really fair, to tell the OP to use differnt tools then the one s/he chose, if the latter would do the job, if used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `scanf_s("%s", ...` wrongly.

Verbatim from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fscanf-s-fscanf-s-l-fwscanf-s-fwscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017):

> The main difference between the more secure functions (that have the **_s** suffix) and the other versions is that the more secure functions require the size in characters of each **c**, **C**, **s**, **S**, and **[** type field to be passed as an argument immediately following the variable.

So if `input` points to the 1st character of a sequence of 20 `char` then it should be:

```
  scanf_s("%s", input, 20);
```

Lessons learned: If in doubt, (re-)read the documentation!